# Как создать представление с вложенной таблицей?

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос

Есть представление со столбцами:

```
("name", "lat", "lon", "P_name", "x1", "x2", "x3")
```

На данный момент, столбец `"name"` не является уникальным, но я хочу его таким сделать.

Хочу создать из этого представления вот такое:

```
('name', 'lat', 'lon', 'obr')
```

где, при обращении к значению столбца `'obr'` "проваливался" бы на таблицу со столбцами:

```
('P_name', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3')
```

Просто для каждой строки существует несколько видов оборудования с разными характеристиками, и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы поле `'name'` стало уникальным.

Подскажите, это вообще возможно сделать?

Еще раз, хочу видеть, когда пытаюсь обратиться к одной строчке, и хочу чтобы с помощью запроса я мог получить все значения столбцов по отдельности.

Ниже примерно то, что описано выше и желал бы получить:

```
"name"  "lat"   "Ion"       'obr'
1       43.22   104.33      |
                        'P_name' 'xl' 'x2' 'x3' 
                            p1     1    2   3 
                            p2     4    5   6

2 ............................
```

Comment: Вы бы пример создания представления привели. Писать с нуля - мало удовольствия.

Comment: Так само то представление уже создано, первое где все в кашу, увы код его не могу прдоставить по причине отстутсвие, я его уже через csvшку  в базу подгрузил.. И стал думать, как мне его модернизировать под мои требования..Возможно ли это вообще..

Comment: Протеворечиво: _Так само то представление уже создано_ и _увы код его не могу прдоставить по причине отстутсвие_, как оно могло быть создано, если код, которым оно было создано, отсутствует. По картинке не понятно, как должен выглядеть конечный результат, а отсутствие входных данных не помогает его понять.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Это называется - объектное представление (*Object View*).

Допустим, есть такие таблицы:

```
create table items (id, name) as 
    select 1, 'item1' from dual union all 
    select 2, 'item2' from dual
/
create table parts (id, itemid, name) as
    select rownum, i.id, i.name||'-'||column_value  
    from items i cross join xmltable ('"part1","part2"')
/
```

Для вложенной таблицы надо создать свой тип данных:

```
create or replace type partT as object (id int, itemid int, name varchar2 (16))
/
create or replace type partsT as table of partT
/
```

Представление надо сделать так:

```
create or replace view itemparts as
    select i.*, cast (multiset (
        select * from parts p where p.itemid = i.id) as partsT) parts
    from items i 
/
```

Запрос и резуьтат:

```
select * from itemparts 
/
        ID NAME  PARTS(ID, ITEMID, NAME)                                         
---------- ----- ----------------------------------------------------------------
         1 item1 PARTST(PARTT(1, 1, 'item1-part1'), PARTT(2, 1, 'item1-part2'))  
         2 item2 PARTST(PARTT(3, 2, 'item2-part1'), PARTT(4, 2, 'item2-part2'))
```

И конечно возможно обратиться к каждой вложенной таблице отдельным запросом:

```
select p.*  
from itemparts i, table (i.parts) p
where i.id = 1
/
        ID     ITEMID NAME            
---------- ---------- ----------------
         1          1 item1-part1     
         2          1 item1-part2
```